# iOS Unity player not appearing in Visual Studio Mac attatch to process menu

Tags: ios, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to attach the visual studio debugger to a running app unity process with script debugging and wait for managed debugger set to true.

I can connect to my iPhone X wirelessly through Xcode fine and it can build and run fine but visual studio cannot see the process for me to attach it to.

[image]

Comment: Unity and visual studio are attached fine and I can breakpoint the editor process without any trouble

Answer (score 0):

It's not a complete fix but I switched to JetBrains Rider which is able to debug the process over a USB connection rather than only through wifi.

There is something wrong with the way Visual Studio was trying to find the Unity process and not being given a way to directly connect to the process via an ip address didn't help.

I hope this helps anyone who was stuck for as long as I was.